# What dielectric liquids can be used as coolants?

Tags: cooling, dielectric

I've seen some interesting videos of people putting their computers in containers with sunflower oil, where they continue to work normal.

Are there any other dielectric liquids that can be used to cool a technical device which is fully submerged in it, possibly without hazard for people, or in a sealed container?

I'm mostly after dielectric liquids that won't deteriorate too fast (in under a month) and lose cooling qualities or become conducting for whatever reason (liquid blooming, though not sure how).

Comment: There was a guy who wrote a blog on EEWeb about immersing his computer in mineral oil.

Comment: I would think that anything that qualifies as a dielectric *could* probably be used as a coolant, though  how effective it is may vary.

Comment: if you looking for complete RoHS coolants then silicon is the answer. But it's more likely a jelly not a liquid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical immersion dielectric coolant is [Florinert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorinert), famously used in the Cray2 and other supercomputers.  It's not cheap, however, and many applications can use oil (i.e. just about every high power transformer out there).  Oil immersion cooling does make for messy service, however.

Comment: But note the warning about Fluorinert - it eventually breaks down into a highly toxic substance!

Answer (score 2):

Light clear mineral oil. See a system here. http://www.pugetsystems.com/aquarium-computer.php